# view excel files in linux command line without installing any packages

Tags: linux, excel

I am connected to a server where I don't have sudo privileges to install packages such as Libreoffice.  I only want to view an excel file might be .xlsx or .xls on linux terminal with a command line, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: scp it to a Windows machine?

Comment: Well, *easy* differs from one person to another. excel files are actually compressed xml files (along with some other data). So, when you decompress an excel file, you will see the file content in xml format. Have fun!

Comment: I tried that but there are many folders with excell files in them and i need to check if which one is complete, I want to able to do it with a command line so it will be faster,thnaks

Comment: You need to check the directories extracted and view all candidate xml files until you find your target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. [XLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154(v=office.12).aspx) and [XLSX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922181(v=office.12).aspx) are binary format data files and you need a tool that can unpack them in order to be able to view the contents. (To be precise, XLSX is compressed XML, but its unsupported readability is exceedingly low.)

Comment: That's a wrong answer. They are not binary files. They are compressed files. You can decompress those and find xml files inside.

Comment: You edited the answer. However, you should remove *binary format*. That's not correct.

Comment: Thanks Roaima. Also what package would be the best to install, libreoffice or something different?

Comment: @joker, IMO _binary format_ is correct. The format may start with a ZIP container but it's not text. Microsoft's definition (added to my answer) also considers XLS to be a binary format file.

Comment: @kutlus I can't advise you on what's _best_ because I don't know your situation. For example, if you're running on a headless system with no GUI installed then LibreOffice or OpenOffice would not be a good suggestion. If you wanted to look at the file structure then something like `xmlstarlet` might be good. But then again it might be way too low-level. I really can't advise you.

Comment: @roaima, do you consider `file.zip` a binary file? or `file.tar.gz` is a binary file? Does a compressed file with a different extension make any difference? That's what I am trying to say. So, using *binary format* would throw readers off.

Comment: You can use unzip in Unix  to uncompress them. However the readability is indeed pretty low

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro just re-checked. XLS is binary format data files in a ZIP container. (`file` returns `data` when querying the content.)

Comment: Yeah, been unzipping them in the last few years. Now if you ask me why, can't remember. Good news, it is not alzheimer yet ;)